# Updating from SVN in Xcode 6.2 failed

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

While I click **Refresh Status** or **Update** from Source Control option in Xcode 6.2, the spinner is shown for infinite time.
Had anyone faced this problem ?
I can't update code from SVN.
How to recover from this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it right.
Password for :

```
Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Repositories
```

was not missing.
It was shown as Authentication failed.
Now when the password was given correctly,everything is working perfectly.